# Setting per-component options in cabal.project.local file

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal-install

I can enable code coverage for a local or other package in `cabal.project` with, e.g.

```
package my-package
  coverage: true
```

But is there a way to specify options for, say, just the library and executable in `my-package` and not the tests?

See: https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nix-local-build.html#configuring-builds-with-cabal-project